# OnSetParameterAsync being called on unrelated component

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am currently working on a project using Blazor WebAssembly as my front end framework, however, I am having some complications with state management, *I think*. This problem was occurring in a large complex solution, so I re-created and simplified it so I could concisely describe it here without all the bloat.

I have a page that contains two components: A list of friends and a list of followers, each with a button to toggle sorting the lists by ascending or descending.

If I override, and put a break point on **OnParametersSetAsync** inside of the **FollowerList** component and click the sort button for the **FriendList** component it hits the break point I set, on the **FollowerList** component.

I was under the impression that **OnParametersSet/Async** would only be called on a component if a property fed to that component had changes or *it's state had changed*.
In my code below you can see I have two separate lists, one is being fed to one component and one to the other, so I'm unsure how this method is being triggered on a component that wasn't touched...

Therefore my questions are: why does it hit the break point on the unrelated component? Is this intentional behavior?

**Page View**

[Index page, with the two lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz5Eo.png)

**Index.razor**

```html
@page "/"
<button value="Sort Friends" @onclick=SortFriends>Sort Friends</button>
<FriendList Friends=SortedFriends />

<button value="Sort Followers" @onclick=SortFollowers>Sort Followers</button>
<FollowerList Followers=SortedFollowers />
```

**Index.cs (Code behind)**

```html
using StateManagementTest.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StateManagementTest.Pages
{
    public partial class Index
    {
        public List<Friend> MyFriends { get; set; }
        public List<Friend> SortedFriends { get; set; }

        public List<Follower> MyFollowers { get; set; }
        public List<Follower> SortedFollowers { get; set; }

        private bool IsFriendsDescending { get; set; }
        private bool IsFollowersDescending { get; set; }

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            MyFriends = new List<Friend>()
            {
                new Friend(){ FirstName = "Jack", LastName = "Sparrow" },
                new Friend(){ FirstName = "Davey", LastName = "Jones"},
                new Friend(){ FirstName = "Iron", LastName = "Man"}
            };

            MyFollowers = new List<Follower>()
            {
                new Follower(){ Username = "user1234" },
                new Follower(){ Username = "abc123" },
                new Follower(){ Username = "david123"} 
            };

            SortedFriends = MyFriends;
            SortedFollowers = MyFollowers;
        }

        private void SortFriends()
        {
            if (!IsFriendsDescending)
            {
                SortedFriends = MyFriends.OrderByDescending(f => f.FirstName).ToList();
                IsFriendsDescending = true;
                return;
            }
            SortedFriends = MyFriends.OrderBy(f => f.FirstName).ToList();
            IsFriendsDescending = false;
            
        }

        private void SortFollowers()
        {
            if (!IsFollowersDescending)
            {
                SortedFollowers = MyFollowers.OrderByDescending(f => f.Username).ToList();
                IsFollowersDescending = true;
                return;
            }
            SortedFollowers = MyFollowers.OrderBy(f => f.Username).ToList();
            IsFollowersDescending = false;

        }
    }
}
```

**FriendList.razor**

```html
<h1>Friends</h1>
@foreach (var friend in Friends)
{
    <div>@friend.FirstName @friend.LastName</div>
}
```

**FriendList.cs (Code behind)**

```html
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using StateManagementTest.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StateManagementTest.Components
{
    public partial class FriendList
    {
        [Parameter]
        public List<Friend> Friends { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**FollowerList.razor**

```html
<h1>Followers</h1>
@foreach (var follower in Followers)
{
    <div>@follower.Username</div>
}
```

**FollowerList.cs (Code behind)**

```html
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using StateManagementTest.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StateManagementTest.Components
{
    public partial class FollowerList
    {
        [Parameter]
        public List<Follower> Followers { get; set; }

        protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
        {
            return base.OnParametersSetAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more research and with my colleague also digging into the issue we have found what was causing this behavior.

I started looking at the component life cycle again [link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and highlighted this section of text:

> **OnParametersSetAsync** or **OnParametersSet** are called:
>
> - After the component is initialized in OnInitialized or OnInitializedAsync.
> - When the parent component re-renders and supplies:
>
>   - Only known primitive immutable types of which at least one parameter has changed.
>   - Any complex-typed parameters. The framework can't know whether the values of a complex-typed parameter have mutated internally, so it treats the parameter set as changed.

So this changed my question to: what is causing the parent component to re-render? Instinctively I started looking at how buttons behave in Blazor and quickly read on the [microsoft docs for event handling in Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#eventcallback) that `StateHasChanged` is called on every UI event, whether that is `onclick`, `onchange` and so on etc. Therefore, when I was clicking the button it was also calling `StateHasChanged`, which caused the component to re-render and reassign subsequent children's parameters, providing they are a complex type.